# How to extract this XML Objects with XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I want to extract the JSONx Data from a XML File to transform in JSON. So i need to extract the json:object from this File

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/ envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<json:object xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/
jsonx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/ schemas/json jsonx.xsd">
<json:string name="Number">XXX</json :string>
<json:string name="name">XXX</json:string> <json:string name="Date">4/84</json:string> <json:string name="amount">123</json:string>
</json:object> </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

the result should look like this

```xml
<json:object xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/
jsonx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/ schemas/json jsonx.xsd">
<json:string name="Number">XXX</json :string>
<json:string name="name">XXX</json:string> <json:string name="Date">4/84</json:string> <json:string name="amount">1234</json:string>
</json:object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming XSLT 2.0 you can use `xsl:copy-of` and `copy-namespaces="no"` to exclude the SOAP namespace:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="//object" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" copy-namespaces="no"/>
</xsl:template>
```